# Javascript click event is not behaving the same on desktop and iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios

This is my sample of my code, I'm using datatable and bootstrap for this, and I added few button to toggle the visibility of the columns, if the columns is hidden, the style of the button is outline, it works fine on desktop, but the problems is when I use my iPhone to test, and if I want to hide the columns, the columns is hidden, but the style is not turning back to outline.

How can I fix this problem?

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<span>Show / Hide:  </span>
<button type="button" class='toggle-vis btn btn-outline-secondary' data-column='0'>ID</button>
<button type="button" class='toggle-vis btn btn-outline-secondary' data-column='1'>Date</button>
<button type="button" class='toggle-vis btn btn-outline-secondary' data-column='2'>Time</button>
<button type="button" class='toggle-vis btn btn-outline-secondary' data-column='3'>Item</button>
<button type="button" class='toggle-vis btn btn-outline-secondary' data-column='4'>Quantity</button>


<table class='table table-bordered' id='dataTable' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1/10</td>
            <td>12:00</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4/10</td>
            <td>14:00</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4/10</td>
            <td>14:00</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
```

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Initialize DataTable
        const table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                // Hide columns based on unique column indices
                { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
            ]
        });

        // Handle button click events
        document.querySelectorAll('button.toggle-vis').forEach((el) => {
            el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let columnIdx = e.target.getAttribute('data-column');
                let column = table.column(columnIdx);

                // Toggle the visibility
                column.visible(!column.visible());

                if (column.visible()) {
                    e.target.classList.replace('btn-outline-secondary', 'btn-secondary');
                } else {
                    e.target.classList.replace('btn-secondary', 'btn-outline-secondary');
                }
            });
        });

        // Initialize button classes based on initial column visibility
        table.columns().every(function() {
            var column = this;
            var columnIdx = column.index();

            if (column.visible()) {
                var button = document.querySelector("button.toggle-vis[data-column='" + columnIdx + "']");
                button.classList.replace('btn-outline-secondary', 'btn-secondary');
            }
            if (!column.visible()) {
                var button = document.querySelector("button.toggle-vis[data-column='" + columnIdx + "']");
                button.classList.replace('btn-secondary', 'btn-outline-secondary');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: add  `el.addEventListener('touchstart', toggleColumnVisibility);` and  replace `e.target` to `e.currentTarget`

Comment: You should consider changing your code block to snipper